# datatool and longtable

Tags: longtable, datatool

i want to print a longtable from a contact list with datatool package. The database has some special characters. This is a small example:

```
\newcommand{\inputfile}{dbase/a.csv}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l|l}
\DTLloadrawdb{title}{\inputfile}%
\DTLforeach*{title}{\name=NAME,\mail=MAIL}{%
\name & \mail\\
}%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

this is the simple CSV file:

```
NAME;MAIL
name01;mail01@address.it
name02;mail02@address.it
name03;mail_03@address.it
```

Please help, i can't understand the following error:

```
(D:\Programmi\miktex_portable\texmfs\install\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty)
(001.aux))
Runaway argument?
\@nil \let \@dtl@line =\@dtl@trmstr \dtl@domappings \@dtl@line     \ifdefempty \ETC
.
! File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@trim.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> ./001.tex
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Load the database outside the longtable. Tabular cells are groups and tabulars are complicated. Don't execute code inside a cell if you don't need too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
%
\begin{document}
\DTLloadrawdb{title}{a.csv}%
\begin{longtable}{l|l}
\DTLforeach*{title}{\name=NAME,\mail=MAIL}{%
\name & \mail\\
}%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to avoid the last blank line created by the loop?